# Flutter: ListView not scrolling

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

**Problem:**

Initially I have disabled `ListView` scrolling, and want to enable it after 3 seconds. The moment app launches and you keep scrolling it for like 5 seconds (**without lifting your finger off the screen**), the `ListView` doesn't scroll.

However it should have scrolled because I am enabling scrolling at 3rd second, the console confirms `ListView enabled` but still I am not able to scroll it.

**Code:**

```
bool _enabled = false; // scrolling disabled initially

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
    print("Scrolling enabled");
    setState(() => _enabled = true); // scrolling enabled after 3 seconds
  });
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: ListView.builder(
      physics: _enabled ? ClampingScrollPhysics() : NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      itemBuilder: (_, i) => ListTile(title: Text("Item $i")),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: I check your code it scroll all time.

Comment: I my cell phone it's working fine with or without lifting fingers. There's no 5 second stop  or any scroll problem i face.

Comment: @HussnainHaidar Thanks for your comment, actually all you need to do is start scrolling the app the moment it launches (don't lift your finger off the screen even once for next 10 seconds), you'll see the `ListView` doesn't scroll.

Comment: There is also a perametor named primary in listview constructor try enabling disabling that one.

Comment: There's also two widgets ignorePointer and absorbPointer try wrapping your list view in one of those widgets.

Comment: And enable disable touch event in one of those widgets not in your listview.

Comment: Try absorbPointer widget I think.

Comment: @HussnainHaidar Thanks but I already tried them (`AbsorbPointer` and `IgnorePointer`, they work the same way above code works.

Comment: This might be a bug, and It's hard to reproduce with normal behavior. The only workaround I could think is you could show a `CircularProgressIndicator` for a few sceonds, and then show `ListView` when app is in stable state.

Comment: @Tokenyet Thanks for your comment, but actually I need this behaviour for my app, I just showed a sample code cause actual code is doing something different using this approach.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce this bug too. Tried to reproduce all that you described in question. Still works fine. Maybe problem in something else, not in scroll physics?

Comment: @AndreyTurkovsky Please try to run this code in real device, the moment app runs, start scrolling to the `ListView` which shouldn't scroll for starting 3 seconds (as code says) and please don't lift your finger off the screen (keep scrolling it for next 5 seconds), you'll see it should have scrolled but fails to scroll.

Comment: @Volleyball I've done this too. Still works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a workaround for this:

```
final _scrollController = ScrollController();
var _firstScroll = true;
bool _enabled = false;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
    setState(() => _enabled = true);
  });
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: GestureDetector(
      onVerticalDragUpdate: (details) {
        if (_enabled && _firstScroll) {
          _scrollController
              .jumpTo(_scrollController.position.pixels - details.delta.dy);
        }
      },
      onVerticalDragEnd: (_) {
        if (_enabled) _firstScroll = false;
      },
      child: AbsorbPointer(
        absorbing: !_enabled,
        child: ListView.builder(
          controller: _scrollController,
          physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
          itemBuilder: (_, i) => ListTile(title: Text("Item $i")),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Sorry this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Why not? It makes the ListView not to scroll the first 3 seconds and if you were scrolling without taking the finger off the screen, then it starts scrolling after 3 seconds

Comment: I forgot to put your initState(), but with that it should work.

Comment: OK, I ran your full code without including my `initState`, I'll include it and give a try in a moment and will let you know.

Comment: It worked, and I swear I wanted to award you bounty but in hurry it was awarded to different user, let me flag this post and hopefully moderators can award it to you.

Comment: OK, I have flagged it, and I am sure you'll get the bounty.

Comment: Here is the [screenshot](https://imgur.com/1nvuInY) of the flag

Answer (score 1):

try this out...

```
class _blabla extends State<blabla> {
Timer _timer;
}

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
    bool _enabled = false;
);
}

  _blablaState() {
    _timer = new Timer(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      setState(() => _enabled = true);
      });
    });
  }

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: ListView.builder(
      physics: _enabled ? ClampingScrollPhysics() : NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      itemBuilder: (_, i) => ListTile(title: Text("Item $i")),
    ),
  );
}

@override
void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _timer.cancel();
}
```

I would also try with physics disabled to see if it makes a difference.  There may be a conflict.

Comment: Hi, did you try it on your own before positing it as answer here?

Comment: My answer is for the timer mentioned in your post.  The gesture detector and absorb pointer are widgets not used in your original post and are a good work-around without using a timer.